# Creating a new environment for multiple choice questions

Tags: environments, indentation

I am trying to create a new environment for multiple choice test questions. I want to make sure that every question has a number and has a constant indentation:

```
1.  Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet.

2.  Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet.
    Lorem ipsum
    dolor sit amet.
```

I think I should use a `minipage` for each question in the environment definition. But I don't know how to adjust the spacing so that each question body is aligned. What should I use for the numbers?

Edit:
I'm attaching my working example. Down below is a portion of the latex.ltx file, with enumerate modified to `cnumerate` to prevent name clashes. I basically want to create an independent environment like the `equation` or `tabular`. Just assume that `\begin{question} \item Lorem. \end{question}` is to create a single indented item with a number.

**Why does cnumerate not print numbers?** The indentation is fine, but there is no numbers. I print \thecnumi for each item, and it works, but the numbers do not show up in the labels.

cnumerate.sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{cnumerate}
          [1999/03/05 v3.00 cnumerate extcnsions (DPC)]

% latex.ltx

\newcount\@cnumdepth \@cnumdepth = 0
\@definecounter{cnumi}
\@definecounter{cnumii}
\@definecounter{cnumiii}
\@definecounter{cnumiv}
\def\cnumerate{%
  \ifnum \@cnumdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@cnumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@cnumctr{cnum\romannumeral\the\@cnumdepth}%
      \expandafter
      \list
        \csname label\@cnumctr\endcsname
        {\usecounter\@cnumctr\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}
\let\endcnumerate =\endlist
\endinput
```

the main file, doc.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cnumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{cnumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum.
\end{cnumerate}
end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: As an aside, might I recommend the [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam) document class? It's a lot easier for things like this. If you need custom question numbers (not automagic), I've written [a few macros](http://pastebin.com/1XUfsTdE) for that.

Comment: @vermiculus The `exam` class does exactly what I want, especially the multiple choice questions. I'm surprised I didn't come across that before. I am going to delve into the source code to make it suit my needs. Perhaps you could post your comment as an answer so I could mark it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might I suggest the [`exam`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/exam)     document class?

Sample document:

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\printanswers

\firstpagefootrule % Use a footer rule on the first page
\runningheadrule   % and so on
\runningfootrule   % and so on (note that this does not cancel out \firstpagefootrule

% define the header for the first page (left, center, right), and so on
\firstpageheader{MATH 351 -- Analysis}{\large \sc Fall 2012 Midterm}{\today}
\firstpagefooter{}{\thepage\ of \numpages}{}
\runningheader{MATH 351 -- Analysis}{Fall 2012 Midterm}{\today}
\runningfooter{}{\thepage\ of \numpages}{}

\begin{document}
Read each question carefully. % Preliminary instructions
\begin{questions}
    \question[50] How long should a man's legs be? % This question is worth 50 points
        \begin{solutionorlines}[1in] % If \printanswers is specified,
                                     % the solution will be printed.
                                     % Otherwise, a box 1 inch tall
                                     % will be printed instead.
            Long enough to reach the ground!
        \end{solutionorlines}
    \question[$\infty$] \lipsum[1]   % arbitrary symbolic point values
        \begin{equation}
        \int_0^{2\pi} \sin x\ \mathbf{d}x
        \end{equation}
        \begin{solutionorbox}[2in]
            \lipsum[2]
            \begin{equation}
            \int_0^{2\pi} \sin x\ \mathbf{d}x = 0
            \end{equation}
        \end{solutionorbox}
\uplevel{\lipsum[1-2]} % Perhaps a different part of the exam? More instructions?
\newpage
    \question \lipsum[4]
        \begin{parts}
            \part[10] \lipsum[5]
                \begin{solutionorbox}[2in]
                    \lipsum[10]
                \end{solutionorbox}
            \part[15] \lipsum[6]
                \begin{solutionorbox}[2in]
                    \lipsum[12]
                \end{solutionorbox}
        \end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

produces [image: a document with space left for the answers], while adding `\printanswers` to the preamble will produce [image: the same document, but with the answers printed.]
If you would like custom question labels (instead of simply incremental), I've written a few new commands for that:

```
% for the `exam` class
\newcommand{\xquestion}[1]{
    % Set the questionlabel to the user's choice
    \renewcommand{\questionlabel}{#1}
    \question % do the question thing
    % and reset it back to default
    \renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\thequestion.}
}
\newcommand{\xpart}[1]{
    % Set the partlabel to the user's choice
    \renewcommand{\partlabel}{#1}
    \part % do the part thing
    % and reset it back to default
    \renewcommand{\partlabel}{(\thepartno)}
}
```

As always, complete documentation for the document class lives on [`CTAN`](http://ctan.mirrorcatalogs.com/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 9):

I think in this instance (considering your output) it is easiest to use a standard `enumerate` environment. Possible alignment or counter formatting/cross-referencing could be manipulated/changed using [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), if/as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.]
  \item \lipsum[1-2]
  \item \lipsum[3-4]
  \item \lipsum[5-6]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provided some dummy text in paragraph form, *Lorem ipsum* style.

Advantages:

1. Easily modifiable via `enumitem`;
2. Breaks across page boundaries; and
3. Standard interface/usage.

For a global take an a specially-created environment `question` that emulates/clones `enumerate`, `enumitem`'s interface provides:

```
\newlist{question}{enumerate}{3}% Clone enumerate as question environment (depth of 3)
\setlist[question]{label=\arabic*.}% All labels are "\arabic."
```

Now you can use

```
\begin{question}
  \item \lipsum[1-2]
  \item \lipsum[3-4]
  \item \lipsum[5-6]
\end{question}
```

For more detail, see the [`enumitem` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) (section **7 Cloning the basic lists**, p 10).

Comment: I've considered using enumerate, but what I want is more complicated:
Create a new environment `question` which has its own contextual syntax, like a tabular environment. You know, like {c c c}. I wanted to borrow from the enumerate package and located `enumerate.sty`, but it was just recently and I didn't have time to understand any of that TeX code. Enumerate has a TeX definition instead of a LaTeX one. Do you have any suggestions on how to clone the definition of enumerate to provide for my needs?

Comment: @cgnieder I am aiming at writing a standalone class with many features. I need to build from the lowest level, so I tried copying and reverse-engineering enumerate.sty. I now need to find where `enumdepth` and `enumi` are defined, because they are not in the sty file. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @OnurSolmaz: It is difficult to provide a more appropriate answer without having details as to what you want to do. Best way to do that would be to It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. At least as far as you can take it. Then you can ask specific questions about it which could be more directly addressed.

Comment: @PeterGrill I isolated the enumerate environment from the files `base/latex.ltx` and `tools/enumerate.sty`. However, when I use the environment, it compiles but does not show the numbers. How and where can I attach the code, as a MWE?

Comment: @OnurSolmaz: You should [edit your original post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/79100/edit) and append/insert the code. Why does the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) solution not seem satisfactory? I don't understand. Is it because you want it to be "stand alone" and not depend on anything else?

Comment: Yes, and also I want different syntax, as I am not preparing lists. I want to use it like the equation environment.

Comment: @OnurSolmaz: If you don't manage it like a list, you may run into problems with the questions not breaking across the page. That may be fine, but it's not very clear from your original question the specific requirements of your new environment. Only the representation, which is mimicked in my answer...

Comment: @Werner Yes, I am sorry about that ^^

I added the example and further explanation

Comment: @Werner btw, the questions are not supposed to break across the pages. I am trying to create a class for multiple choice exams, i.e. university entrance tests. These have a very specific format, and the existence of such a format would make the lives of many people much easier. You can have a look at [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8Z-3siTir7qRUhBRUw1Nk1TN2FLNDJQZlBCUFlFdw/edit) to have an idea.

Comment: @OnurSolmaz: I'll look through your code later tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out that each class defines its own style enumeration labels. So I borrowed from article and modified for cnumerate. Adding the following to cnumerate.sty solves the problem. Also, the `choices` environment from the `exam` does something similar to what I need, and can be modified accordingly.

```
\newtoks\@cnLab\renewcommand\thecnumi{\@arabic\c@cnumi}
\renewcommand\thecnumii{\@alph\c@cnumii}
\renewcommand\thecnumiii{\@roman\c@cnumiii}
\renewcommand\thecnumiv{\@Alph\c@cnumiv}
\newcommand\labelcnumi{\thecnumi.}
\newcommand\labelcnumii{(\thecnumii)}
\newcommand\labelcnumiii{\thecnumiii.}
\newcommand\labelcnumiv{\thecnumiv.}
\renewcommand\p@cnumii{\thecnumi}
\renewcommand\p@cnumiii{\thecnumi(\thecnumii)}
\renewcommand\p@cnumiv{\p@cnumiii\thecnumiii}
```