# creating a special template for multiple-choice quiz

Tags: graphics, environments, templates, document-classes

Does any one know how I can obtain (access) a *format*, *template*, *macro* or a *special* `documentclass` in which I have a template for creating some pages of a multiple-choice quiz same as

[image: here]

I read [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79100/creating-a-new-environment-for-multiple-choice-questions), but I think it cannot help me for this aim.

Comment: Have you seen these packages? https://ctan.org/topic/exam. Also, this answer looks somewhat similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12633/121944.